# Override group_vars by external source

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have a pilote project keeping many common variables in `group_vars`.

```
group_vars/
  group1.yml
  group2.yml
  group3.yml
```

For different implementations (usually per client), I'd like to maintain reserved file which overrides the content of `group_vars`, where the content of that file could have following format, i.e. `client1.yml` :

```
group1:
  var11_to_override: "foo"
  var12_to_override: "bar"
group2:
  var21_to_override: "foo"
  var22_to_override: "bar"
```

Is there a simple possibility to say to Ansible that file `client1.yml` overrides `group_vars` content?

The module `include_vars` could be certainly the first step together with `set_facts` within a loop, but it requires probably complicated jinja2 filter expressions ...

Have I to write a new module or filter updating `hostvars`?

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence. At first glimpse, I would keep your current files in inventory `group_vars` folder and add the override files group by group in the playbook `group_vars` folder.

Comment: @Zeitounator Unfortunately I must keep the format of `client1.yml` file and can't be placed in the same folder as `group_vars` files. In the future of this project, I should be able to get the same content from a REST API.

Comment: What is a "client" in this context?  Is it a system being managed by Ansible, or is it your customer, so that `client1.yml` holds customer-specific data?

Comment: @Jack For each client some values in `group_vars` changes, but the major part still the same; that's why we want to maintain a kind of overlay file overriding some default values instead of replacing whole files in `group_vars` folder.

Comment: @ibt23sec5 That does not answer my question.  Is a "client" a system being managed by Ansible, or is "client" your customer?

Comment: @Jack managed by Ansible

Comment: Then just put `client1.yml` and `client2.yml` into the `host_vars` directory.  They will override anything in the group_vars` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved by custom filter updating a dict by another:

`filter_plugins/vars_update.py`

```
import copy
import collections

class FilterModule(object):
    def update_hostvars(self, _origin, overlay):
        origin = copy.deepcopy(_origin)
        for k, v in overlay.items():
            if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
                origin[k] = self.update_hostvars(origin.get(k, {}), v)
            else:
                origin[k] = v 
        return origin

    def filters(self):
        return {"update_hostvars": self.update_hostvars}
```

.. and using this filter when updating all variables:

```
- name: Include client file
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ client_file_path }}"
    name: client_overlay

- name: Update group_vars by template client
  set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][item.key] | update_hostvars(item.value) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ client_overlay }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the examples given in this thread i made my own solution:

1. The "external source" feeds in an inventory item using --extra-vars "@". The file content itself is uploaded as base64 encoded content and then decoded/written to fs.
2. The external file has a list of overrides per role/group like so:

   ```
        role_overrides: [{
          "groups": [
              "my-group"
          ],
          "overrides": {
              "foo": "value",
              "bar": "value",
          }
      },
   ```

but then jsonified obviously...

3. The filter module

   #!/usr/bin/env python

class FilterModule(object):
def filters(self):
return {
"filter_hostvars_overrides": self.filter_hostvars_overrides,
}

```
def filter_hostvars_overrides(self, role_overrides, group_names):
    """
    filter the overrides for the ones to apply for this host

    [
      {
          "groups": [
              "my-group"
          ],
          "overrides": {
              "foo: 42,
          }
      },

    :param group_names: List of groups this host is member of
    :param role_overrides: document with all overrides; to be filtered using groups_names
    :return: items to be set
    """
    overrides = {}
    for idx, per_group_overrides in enumerate(role_overrides):
        groups = per_group_overrides.get("groups", [])
        if set(groups).intersection(set(group_names)):
            overrides.update(per_group_overrides.get("overrides", {}))
    return overrides
```

4. The play code:

   ```
        - name: Apply group overrides
         set_fact:
           "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
         with_dict: "{{ role_overrides | filter_hostvars_overrides(group_names) }}"
   ```